# Add right click option to chrome extension's icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Most of these questions seem to pertain to adding a right click to elements and pages using context menus. I would like to know if it is possible to add a right click option to a Chrome extension's icon. I.e. put an option such as "Documentation" between "Options" and "Disable"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add contextmenu items to a Chrome extension's browser action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468429/add-contextmenu-items-to-a-chrome-extensions-browser-action-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for that currently and I am not aware of any in the works.

If there was anything, it would be in the [Browser Action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) or [Page Action](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html) documentation.

Comment: Seems like something that should exist. But that's how these things go: you don't know they don't exist until you need them.

Yeah, I was perusing the Browser Action page trying to find something I overlooked.

Comment: This is no longer true, you CAN add to that contextMenu. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26760703/2278186

Answer (score 21):

You can use Chrome create **contextMenus** API and set contexts="browser_action"

**Example**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "type":"checkbox",
  "checked":true,
  "title":"Connect via Cloud",
  "contexts":["browser_action"],
  "onclick":function(info, tab) {
      console.log(info);
  }
});
```