# Adding to the “right-click” menu for a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, right-click

So most Google Chrome Extension have an "Options" Page, which is navigable by right-clicking on the extension icon.

Is it possible to add another entry to ***that*** right-click menu?  Just when you're right-clicking your extension icon, not adding to the browser context menu in general.

For example under the "Options" option have an "Enable/Disable Alerts" option which changes dynamically between "Enable Alerts" and "Disable Alerts"

Or is this only possible by adding to the general right-click browser context menu using the ContextMenu APIs?

Comment: Similar questions, with answers: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715370/add-more-custom-option-for-a-chrome-extension-context-menu 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083638/add-right-click-option-to-chrome-extensions-icon 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468429/add-contextmenu-items-to-a-chrome-extensions-browser-action-button

Answer (score -1):

Till date it is only possible to add [**Context Menu**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) within [**Browser View Port**](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html).