# How do I add context menu in MV3 Chrome extension popup icon?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to add the Share on FB/ Twitter and Facebook Page links on my popup icon content menu.

It's very convenient to do this in MV2 extensions.

But how do I do that in MV3 ones?

[image]

Comment: It's the same as in MV2 but you'll use `action` context instead of `browser_action`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add contextmenu items to a Chrome extension's browser action button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468429/add-contextmenu-items-to-a-chrome-extensions-browser-action-button)

Comment: It seems not working in MV3, would you mind sending an example here?

Comment: You can add your [MCVE](/help/mcve) here so people would look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this appears to not work on MV3.

The docs say [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) is not available for MV3, and although ["browser_action"](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contextMenus/#type-ContextType) is still listed as a valid ContextType, it seems to have no effect.

Adblock (for example) has custom context menu items for their icon, but that's because they still use MV2.

Maybe adblock still using MV2 (or just the fact that MV2 still offers exclusive features) is a good indication that MV3 is still limited/incomplete and might not be the best idea to use, yet.